# int to padded-zeroes string

Tags: c, string, int, type-conversion

I've got a number that needs to be compared against 3 character strings. The number is never more than 3 digits long.

So for example, I need to compare 3, 300, and 13 to strings like '003' '300' and '013'.

I think the easiest way to compare would be if I could get the ints into their string format, and then use `strcmp` to compare '003' to '003'.

I'm just not sure how I can determine how many characters need to be padded, and particularly how to assign and convert properly.

Any suggestions? I was thinking I could check if the `number - 100 < 0`. If it was, it means the number needs to be padded not just converted. I could also do `number - 10 < 0` to see if it's a number like `13` or `3`. So I can determine the exact number of zeroes to pad, but I'm lost after that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I think the easiest way to compare would be if I could get the ints
>   into their string format, and then use strcmp to compare '003' to '003'

I think it would be easiest to use `strtoul` and convert the strings to integers.

```
3 == strtoul("003", NULL, 10);
```

Comment: so "003" will correctly turn into 3? It has no problem handling leading zeroes? ... reading the man page, won't it think 003 is octal?

Comment: @user974703 It has no problem with leading zeroes.

Comment: @user974703: As long as you specify base 10, the leading zeros are no problem. If you leave the base unspecified (0), leading zeros will cause the number to be interpreted as octal.

Answer (score 3):

For the purpose of convention, let's call the number you're comparing `(int) num` and the string `(char *) str`.

You could dump the number into a string buffer using `s(n)printf` and compare the resulting strings:

```
char str2[16];
snprintf(str2, sizeof(str2), "%03d", num);
if (strcmp(str, str2) == 0) { ... }
```

It'd probably be easier to just convert the string to an integer and compare THAT, though:

```
if (num == atoi(str)) { ... }
```